# How to resolve runtime error when writing from excel to word on a Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word, ole

I'm using Excel version 16.54 on a Macbook Pro. The following is a portion of code that should take some values from an Excel worksheet and write them in a Word document.The Word document is stored in the same folder as the Excel file.
The whole process of writing in the Word document is triggered by a button in the Excel file.(A function that runs when the button is clicked)

At first I get a prompt with the question "Is Microsoft Word Open?".
If I click on Yes (Word is open) ... I get a runtime automation error.
If I click on No (Word is open) ... I get a runtime automation error.
If I click on No (Word is closed) ... I get a runtime automation error.
If I close Word and try again I must click on No in order for it to start writing in the word document.

My problem is that I always have to go trough the error at least once in order for it to start working.
Is there something wrong with my code or is it simply because i'm using a Macbook?

Update: It runs with no problems on Windows.

```
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object 
    Dim exBk As Workbook
    Dim exSht As Worksheet
    Set exBk = ThisWorkbook

    filepath = exBk.Path & "/" & Worksheets("Content").Range("B2").Value
        a = MsgBox("Is Microsoft Word Open?", vbYesNo)
        If a = vbYes Then
            Set wdApp = GetObject(filepath, "Word.Application")
        Else
            Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(filepath)
        End If
    wdApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. This is simply due to Office on macOS. If you search SO you will find that this has question has been asked before. You may get a better answer if you post your question in the [Apple forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You will receive an error on Windows too using GetObject when Word isn't already running. That's why I suggest a tryGetWord-routine - see below.

Comment: Office for Mac using a mini-port of Windows OLE technology. It's poorly written. You should send a bug report to Microsoft. Set up a page that shows your code so it can be reproduced. Click on the "person-with-speech-bubble" icon in the upper right corner of the program window and choose I don't like something. Describe the problem in detail, include a screenshot showing your code and submit. They are unlikely to reply.

Answer (score -1):

I am using the following a tryGet-function to return the WordApp.
This is one of the occassions where I use On error resume next.

Tested on Windows - not Mac

```vb
Sub test_getWord()

Dim wdApp As Object
If tryGetWordApp(wdApp) = False Then
    MsgBox "Word could not be started."
    Exit Sub
End If

wdApp.Visible = True

End Sub



Public Function tryGetWordApp(wdApp As Object) As Boolean
'Generic function to retrieve Word Application - regardless of wether app is already open or has to be opened.
'Returns true if wdApp could be set, otherwise false

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err > 0 Or wdApp Is Nothing Then
    'Word not yet open
    Err.Clear
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    If Err = 0 Then tryGetWordApp = True
Else
    tryGetWordApp = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```